# Is it right to use GIT for version control of HTML pages

Tags: html, node.js, json, git

I am working on an app that creates automatic blog HTML pages using JSON and also has to provide versioning for that blog.

1. Creating HTML using JSON files
2. Creating a GIT tag whenever User creates a version.
3. If the user wanted to see the previous version of that blog I am simply checking out that file to given tag and fetch the file and again creating HTML using that JSON file.

Questions

1. Is it right to use GIT for the above purpose?
2. If yes, Are there any precautions that I have to take?
3. If no, Is there any alternatives for saving the previous version of a file except saving each file for each version?

Note: I am using Node.js for creating GIT tags and checkout to tags

Comment: It sounds like a slightly odd application design. Why generate static HTML for the blog? Most sites of that type store the data in a database and use a HTML template (or set of templates) into which that content is retrieved from the data store and inserted into the template whenever a user wants to view a particular entry in the blog, and the resulting HTML is served directly to the browser, not saved as a static copy on disk. If you wanted to keep a history you could design your database to do that without too much trouble, so it would have extra rows in the tables for old versions of data

Comment: Is there any special reason your app doesn't take that standard approach? I ask this because in your design, the HTML pages are effectively copies of the site content, rather than the source code, and it's not usual to store the site content in source control, only the actual code which is used to create and display the content is normally stored. Some other store, e.g. database, which itself can be backed up separately, is used to store the content. If you store the content with the code then it's much harder to deploy your app to different environments for testing etc

Comment: Hi @ADyson sir, I am using two repositories One is for Source code and one is for data files. And I do templatize my content according to different templates my designers gave me. I am asking Why not use this approach?

Comment: Ok. Well a source control system is a reasonable way to store files if you need versioning and history. But as I mentioned, I would seriously question whether storing static files is a good way to design your site. It introduces several problems, e.g. disk space, maintenance etc.

Comment: For example, think about if you want to change the layout or colour scheme of the site after some time. If you store static copies of your HTML along with each piece of content, then you cannot do it, because you would have to modify hundreds of HTML files. If you just create the HTML on-demand from a template then it's easy - you only have to modify the template, and after that every request to view a blog post (no matter how old the post is) will use the new template, because it is re-created from the template every time it's viewed.

Comment: Think about how this StackOverflow site works. Do you suppose they store a separate file for each question? Of course not. They would use up huge amounts of space, they would be unable to make changes to the layout, and the interactive parts such as comments would not be able to work. Instead there will be one template for a post, containing placeholders for the question, answers, comments, adverts etc, and when you view a question, it gets all the data from the database each time, puts it into the template and sends it to the browser. No static HTML is involved.

Comment: I would seriously suggest that you reconsider your design approach. No-one else does a blog or similar site in the way you're proposing. There are good reasons why they don't. I have highlighted a couple of the obvious reasons, but there are others as well. It's not a sustainable or practical way to operate a modern website.

Comment: Sorry @ADyson sir, I gave you half info in the previous comment, I am not storing any HTML file I am storing only JSON files that are structured according to my rule engine that converts those JSON's into HTML whenever a user requests a page. And each template has its predefined CSS in another place according to the theme. Does this statement change any of your views sir?

Comment: But if you're not storing the HTML on disk then how are you expecting to check it into a Git repository? or are you talking about storing the JSON files in Git, rather than the HTML? Maybe I misunderstood you, it's not entirely clear from the question. P.S. I think it would almost certainly be more efficient to use a database instead of files on disk (even a NoSQL database which can store raw JSON) - retrieval / searching / filtering / ordering of the data will be far simpler and quicker. And history/versioning would still be very possible.

Comment: Yes @ADyson sir, Storing JSON's in GIT.

Comment: Right I see. Well then yes you could use Git. But I think if your site grows it will become less efficient. So I would still consider using a database of some kind to store that information instead of files on disk.

Comment: Thanks Sir, I got this idea of using GIT instead of using DB. I thought it would reduce the complexity of our code but I understand it is a risky process if I have too many files or if my app keeps on storing the files.

Answer (score 0):

You should use git for every project, ask if it's right only if you have a ton of binary files.

Comment: Hi @Fabiosoft, What happens if I have ton files. I wanted to know the risk before doing it full scale.

Comment: Git is very efficient at scale. Big companies use it too

Answer (score 0):

I've seen people use git for content writing and articles, remember it is an efficient version control systems and as long as you wish to have past versions of your project( you always should), you should use git.

even if you are not pushing to a remote repository, it's better to have some VCS implemented in all your projects.